# Exception and question involving Android Callable Wrapper

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have two questions about Android Callable Wrappers which I hope you guys could answer.

Question 1. Xamarin auto-generates the following constructor in the ACW of a class:

```
public ConsumerService (java.lang.String p0, android.content.Context p1)
{
super (p0, p1);
if (getClass () == ConsumerService.class)
mono.android .TypeManager.Activate ("Test.Tizen.Droid.ConsumerService, Test.Tizen.Droid", "System.String, mscorlib:Android.Content.Context, Mono.Android ", this, new java.lang.Object[] { p0, p1 });
}
```

But then throws following exception on startup of the app: `System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type '.mscorlib' from assembly 'Mono.Android , Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'`.

Which references to this part in the constructor: `mscorlib:Android.Content.Context`. Removing the "mscorlib:" fixes the exception, but my question is, why does it throw an exception in the first place since Xamarin auto-generates this?

Question 2. Can anyone tell me why Xamarin only takes the base class into account when generating the ACW of a derived class, and doesn't take the constructors of the derived class into account?